# RewriteRule for favicon in apache httpd.conf

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set a favicon for my mediawiki site. The icon should be available at `https://mywiki.net/favicon.ico`

**setup**

- Apache basepath is `/var/www/html`
- The mediawiki is sitting in `/var/www/html/mywiki`
- The path to the favicon is `/var/www/html/mywiki/favicon.ico`
- I'm redirecting all requests from `mywiki.net` to `https://mywiki.net/wiki`
- I'm using Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) on an AWS EC2 machine

**httpd.conf**

After reading through the [Short Url manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) I put these redirects on the bottom of my apache config:

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico /var/www/html/mywiki/favicon.ico [L]
Alias /wiki /var/www/html/mywiki/index.php
RedirectMatch ^/$ /wiki
```

In the conf.d I'm including an redirect-everyting-to-https config file. This was autogenerated by letsencrypt:

**conf.d/le-redirect-mywiki.net.conf**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
ServerName mywiki.net 

ServerSignature Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/redirect.error.log
LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

The wiki so far works, except that it doesn't have a favicon. If I `wget https://mywiki.net/favicon.ico` I'm getting a 404. In the logs I can see

```
==> /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log <==
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [19/May/2017:20:43:37 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

This means this redirect is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico /var/www/html/mywiki/favicon.ico [L]
```

What would be the proper redirect rule for the favicon?

I figured out I can just put the favicon in the base path of apache (`/var/www/html/favicon.ico`). This works, but I would rather keep everything in my `mywiki` directory (`/var/www/html/mywiki/favicon.ico`).

Comment: the replacement path must be a request uri `/mywiki/favicon.ico`. Use alias `Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/html/mywiki/favicon.ico` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/favicon\.ico$ /var/www/html/mywiki/favicon.ico
```